# How can I parse my JSON file that contains strings, and numbers, and assign each category to a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get my JSON file content into a JS variable, so I can start using what was in the JSON file. I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse each category and assigning them to a variable in JS.

So on the JS side, I would like for it to be somthing like this:

```
var 1 = jeff
var 2 = Internal
```

and so on...

Comment: "You don't". Use arrays/dictionaries/etc to deal with the data. This may include transforming the data (in JavaScript, *after* using JSON.parse) such that the final structure is more like: `invites = {1: {invite_id: 1, .. }, 300: {invite_id: 300, .. }}` - eg. so it can be accessed by id-as-a-key (`invites[300].vector`) - or whatnot

Comment: Please create an actual output you'd expect from your JSON content. Things like `var 1 = jeff` don't make any sense in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()`. I'm assuming the `JSON` is in a file. Also assuming `var 1 = ...` means first `var one = ...`

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(file);
var one = jsonObject.invites[someIndex].sender_id; // "jeff"
var two = jsonObject.invites[someIndex].vector; // "Internal"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to create global variables by the same name as json object properties.

```
data = {
    "invite_id": 1,
    "sender_id": "jeff",
    "sig_id": 25121,
    "invite": "The Owner has invited you",
    "vector": "Internal",
    "invite_time": 1398892261,
    "status": 'read'
}


//Iterate the object
for (var property in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        window[property] = data[property]  //create global variables by property name
    }
}

console.log(vector); //outputs 'Internal'
```

But the correct pattern is to create your variables within a private scope object. You can do it by replacing `window` with your private scope object.